# Problema con variable definida en ambito global que no puedo cambiar a traves de una funcion -javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo que realizar un juego de papel piedra o tijera, al ejecutarlo no me corre la funcion desde donde recibo informacion cuando el usuario hace click en el boton, pero al ejecutar un console.log dentro de la funcion si me aparece el valor del usuario.
Quiero almacenar el ID del boton presionado para luego ser comparado contra lo generado por un math.random (que funciona bien).

```
let elecciondejugador
//genero funcion para poder obtener la eleccion del user por el boton
function playerSelection() {
  botones.forEach((accion) => {
    accion.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      elecciondejugador=e.target.id 
//solo aca puedo obtener el valor correcto de la variable
      e.stopPropagation;
    });
  });
}
//logica para comparar y elegir ganador o perdedor

function game(computerEleccion, playerEleccion) {
  if (playerEleccion === computerEleccion) {
    console.log("tie");
  }
  if (
    (playerEleccion === "ROCK" && computerEleccion === "SCISSORS") ||
    (playerEleccion === "SCISSORS" && computerEleccion === "PAPER") ||
    (playerEleccion === "PAPER" && computerEleccion === "ROCK")
  ) {
    playerScore++;
    console.log("player");
  }
  if (
    (computerEleccion === "ROCK" && playerEleccion === "SCISSORS") ||
    (computerEleccion === "SCISSORS" && playerEleccion === "PAPER") ||
    (computerEleccion === "PAPER" && playerEleccion === "ROCK")
  ) {
    computerScore++;
    console.log("computer");
  }
}
game(computerPlay(), playerSelection())
```

Comment: No se si tendrá que ver con tu problema, pero sintácticamente pones mal esto: `e.stopPropagation;` pues debe ser esto: `e.stopPropagation();`